# How should I ask a question when the context is long?

Tags: discussion, questions

The [How to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) guide advises to be specific, provide details and context.

However, there is a lot to say before the question I have in mind actually makes sense and when I provide said context, including what led me to do what I try to do, the logs I gathered, the commands I tried when investigating and the outputs I received. My question becomes very long; no less than 13,488 characters according to *[wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) -c*.

Just before submitting my question, Stack Exchange said that it did not find any way to improve my answer and I therefore proceeded to publish the question. But Stack Exchange won't let me actually publish it, because my question "looks like spam".

Now I published [a much shortened version of the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634391/autofs-fails-to-mount-nfs-shared-autofs-bind-mounted-directory-but-manual-mount) which lacks many details I believe would be useful to anyone to help. What is the best way to add all the necessary context in such a way that my question is not blocked based on *spam* suspicion?

Comment: The *looks like spam*  is often caused by not applying the correct markdown. In the post you linked I see stuff that is probably better served if formatted as a code block. You can select the whole block and then press CTRL+K or click the code icon in the toolbar. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: As for having two accounts, try merging them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/323179

Comment: Indeed, now that I formatted my question more carefully, stackexchange accepted it. Merging account is on the way